# angular progress bar using ng-style goes back

Tags: css, angularjs

I have issue with ng-style and progress bar

I'm using file uploader module from the following link : https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

The issue is the progress bar goes back with the animation instead of starting from 0.

I checked the values and it does start from 0, than progress until 100,
but the progress looks like it goes back.

Not sure what am i doing wrong,

If you have any idea, please share it with me.

I attached animated gif to show the scenario

and my html code:

```
<div ng-if="item.progress <= 100" class="upload-progress-bar">
<div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I also tried to move the ng-style to a function on the controller,

or add nt-init to the html like that:

```
<div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }" ng-init="item.progress = 0"></div>
```

but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you output the value item.progress as text in your screen? i.e. add <div>{{item.progress}}</div>? That should tell you (and us) if it's a problem with the values in item.progress or something else.

Comment: @Sarhanis i did that, the text is correct the progress set to 0 but the animation make it go back

Comment: The figure item.progress changes over time, and it might be going backwards as well as forwards.

Comment: Could you isolate the code and add it in a plunker?

Comment: What about the code that updates `item.progress`?

Comment: @CosminAbabei the project is too complicated to upload it to plunker, i can't issloated it cause it need a server

Comment: @zeroflagL the code who update item.progress is https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Comment: If `item` is an instance of `FileItem` then you cannot change `item.progress` yourself, so `item.progress = 0` is useless. It's also not an Angular or `ngStyle` problem. Without seeing your code it's hard to tell what the problem is. Maybe there isn't a problem at all or a bug in the upload component. It looks like the estimation starts at or near 100% but is then adjusted. After that it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks for the explnation, you are right item.progress is instance of FileItem and it can't bet change, although it start from 0, i can see it when i print it to the screen, the thing is that ng-style for some reason change the width with animation and therefore (i think) take the progress back although each item has it's own progress bar, so i really not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help
The issue was solves by removing

```
track bv $index
```

from the ng-repeat.

i'm not sure what cause this issue, but that's defiantly solved it.